# Date data type in Oracle, 12 pm

Tags: sql, oracle, date, sqldatatypes, to-char

How do I know if the hour 00:00:00 in a date field means 12 pm or means nothing, null, without looking for the data source of this table?

**FORMAT DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS**

DATE_WITHOUT_HOUR: 03/01/2022 **00:00:00**

DATE_WITH_HOUR: 04/01/2022 21:30:00

**FORMAT DD/MM/YYYY HH:MI:SS**

DATE_WITHOUT_HOUR: 03/01/2022 **12:00:00**

DATE_WITH_HOUR: 04/01/2022 09:30:00

The previous date was a result of a insert of two values: ('03/01/2022', '04/01/2022 21:30:00')

After that insert how anyone knows the hour of the first date is meaningless without checking out the insert?

Thanks!

Comment: BTW 00:00:00 never means 12pm, it always means midnight.

Comment: It seems like you have answered your own question. `'HH24:MI:SS'` does the trick, right? `'HH:MI:SS'` isn't very useful without including 'am'/'pm'.

Answer (score 1):

In Oracle, a `DATE` is a binary data type consisting of 7 bytes that represent century, year-of-century, month, date, hour, minute and second. It **ALWAYS** has those components and it is **NEVER** stored with any particular formatting.

You cannot have a `DATE` without an hour.

*Note: The client application you use to talk to the database may chose to implicitly apply a format to binary date values it receives to make those values more meaningful to you, the user; however, this is a function of the client application you are using and is not something done by the database.*

---

If you want to *display* a `DATE` then you can use `TO_CHAR` then:

- The date format `DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS` is unambiguous as the hours will be displayed using the 24-hour clock.
- The date format `DD/MM/YYYY HH12:MI:SS AM` (and `HH` is the same as `HH12`) is also unambiguous as, although the hours will be displayed using a 12-hour clock, a meridian indicator is shown that disambiguates between AM and PM.
- The date format `DD/MM/YYYY HH12:MI:SS` is ambiguous and there is no way to differentiate between AM and PM. You should not use this format model without the meridian indicator.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle stores dates in its internal format. It is up to you to take care about the way you store values into `DATE` datatype columns. If you stored it as

```
to_date('2022-01-31 20:52', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi')
```

then that's the value.

While retrieving value from the table, you have different options, but - any you use will result in the same value (it just might be differently *displayed*):

```
SQL> create table t_date (col date);

Table created.

SQL> insert into t_date values (to_date('2022-01-31 20:52', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi'));

1 row created.
```

Default NLS settings in my database don't even display 4 digits for years; time component isn't visible:

```
SQL> select * from t_date;

COL
--------
31.01.22
```

`TO_CHAR` with 24-hours time format:

```
SQL> select to_char(col, 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss') result from t_date;

RESULT
-------------------
31.01.2022 20:52:00
```

`TO_CHAR` with AM/PM:

```
SQL> select to_char(col, 'dd/mm/yyyy hh:mi am') result from t_date;

RESULT
-------------------
31/01/2022 08:52 PM
```

Altering session's date format mask:

```
SQL> alter session set nls_date_format = 'dd mon yyyy, hh24:mi';

Session altered.

SQL> select * from t_date;

COL
------------------
31 jan 2022, 20:52

SQL>
```

Whatever I did, that value remains the same. Therefore, it is really up to you.